# Turn characters into sensible things (tokenizing/lexing)

Tags: c, lexical-analysis

I'm writing [a programming language](https://github.com/nic-hartley/concaten). It's something I've been working on and off on for the last year or so, but recently, I've decided to buckle down and *do it*.

As part of the language, I wrote a tokenizer. Its job is to turn a stream of human-readable characters into data the language can do something with. That allows for a couple of neat abstractions, as well as separating my concerns (the parsing code doesn't have to worry about the actual in-text layout of the code, just the tokens; the tokenizer doesn't parse, it just tokenizes)

I realize I could have let `yacc` do the work, but half the point of this project is to <del>fill out my lackluster resume</del> be able to say "I made this from scratch".

Quick note beforehand (as opposed to the previous paragraphs): This uses [StringBuilder](https://github.com/nic-hartley/concaten/blob/master/stringbuilder.c). I've already [put](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/155286/62850) it [up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/155978/62850) for review, and actually incorporated a few suggestions from that into this.

#### `tokenizer.h`

```
#ifndef CONCATEN_TOKENIZER_H
#define CONCATEN_TOKENIZER_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE
# define TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE 256
#endif
#if TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE <= 0
# error TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE cannot be <= 0
#endif

struct FileSource {
    FILE *fptr;
    unsigned char next_chars[TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE];
    size_t next_chars_pos;
    size_t eof; // if we're at EOF, this marks where in next_chars it is
};
struct StringSource {
    char *begin;
    char *end;
    char *cur_pos;
};
struct Tokenizer {
    union {
        struct StringSource string;
        struct FileSource file;
    } source;
    bool is_from_file;
    char next_char;
    char *origin;
    size_t origin_len;
    size_t line, index;
    int error;

    bool just_started;
};

enum TokenType {
    TKN_UNKNOWN, TKN_WORD, TKN_STRING, TKN_REGEX,
    TKN_INTEGER, TKN_REAL, TKN_IDENTIFIER
};
struct Token {
    char *raw;
    size_t raw_len;
    char *origin;
    size_t origin_len;
    size_t line, index;
    enum TokenType type;
};

struct Token tkn_empty(size_t line, size_t index);
char *tkn_type_name(int);
void tkn_free(struct Token *);
// object_t tkn_value(Token) // defined in object.h

struct Tokenizer tknr_from_string(const char *, const char *origin);
struct Tokenizer tknr_from_filepath(const char *path);
bool tknr_next(struct Tokenizer *, struct Token *);
char *tknr_err_to_string(int);
bool tknr_end(struct Tokenizer *);
void tknr_free(struct Tokenizer *);

#endif // ndef CONCATEN_TOKENIZER_H
```

#### `tokenizer.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "tokenizer.h"
#include "stringbuilder.h"

#define ERROR(code) do{\
    printf("Tokenizer error %d unhandled at " __FILE__ ":%d", code, __LINE__);\
    exit(code % 100);\
    }while(0)

//define TOKENIZER_OPS_FAIL            1000
// define CTOR_FAIL                     1100
//  define CTOR_STR_FAIL                 1110
#    define CTOR_STR_MALLOC_FAIL          1111
#    define CTOR_STR_BAD_STRLEN_FAIL      1112
#    define CTOR_STR_NULL_ARG_FAIL        1113
//  define CTOR_FILE_FAIL                1120
#    define CTOR_FILE_MALLOC_FAIL         1121
#    define CTOR_FILE_BAD_STRLEN_FAIL     1122
#    define CTOR_FILE_NULL_ARG_FAIL       1123
#    define CTOR_FILE_FOPEN_FAIL          1124
// define READ_CHAR_FAIL                1200
#   define FILE_READ_FAIL                1210
#    define FILE_READ_EOF_FAIL            1211
//  define STRING_READ_FAIL              1220
#    define STRING_READ_EOS_FAIL          1221
// define NEXT_TOKEN_FAIL               1300
#   define NT_MALLOC_FAIL                1301
#   define NT_NEW_SB_FAIL                1302
#   define NT_SB_FREE_COPY_FAIL          1303
//define TOKENIZER_SYNTAX_FAIL         1500
#  define SYN_NO_SEPARATION_FAIL        1501
#  define SYN_UNEXPECTED_END_FAIL       1502
// define SYN_STR_FAIL                  1510
#   define SYN_STR_MULTILINE_FAIL        1511
// define SYN_NUM_FAIL                  1520
#   define SYN_NUM_ILLEGAL_DIGIT_FAIL    1521
// define SYN_RGX_FAIL                  1530
#   define SYN_RGX_BAD_FLAG_FAIL         1531

struct Token tkn_empty(size_t line, size_t index) {
    return (struct Token) {
            .type = TKN_UNKNOWN,
            .index = index,
            .line = line,
            .origin = NULL,
            .raw = NULL,
            .origin_len = 0,
            .raw_len = 0,
    };
}

char *tkn_type_name(int t) {
    switch (t) {
        case TKN_UNKNOWN:
            return "unknown";
        case TKN_WORD:
            return "word";
        case TKN_STRING:
            return "string";
        case TKN_REGEX:
            return "regex";
        case TKN_INTEGER:
            return "integer";
        case TKN_REAL:
            return "real";
        case TKN_IDENTIFIER:
            return "identifier";
        default:
            abort();
    }
}

void tkn_free(struct Token *t) {
    free(t->raw);
    t->raw = NULL;
    free(t->origin);
    t->origin = NULL;
}

char read_char(struct Tokenizer *);

struct Tokenizer tknr_from_string(const char *mem, const char *origin) {
    struct Tokenizer ret = (struct Tokenizer) {
            .origin = NULL,
            .is_from_file = false,
            .source.string = (struct StringSource) {
                    .begin = NULL,
                    .end = NULL,
                    .cur_pos = NULL
            },
            .next_char = '\0',
            .just_started = true,
            .error = 0
    };

    if (!mem || !origin) {
        ret.error = CTOR_STR_NULL_ARG_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }
    size_t mem_len = strlen(mem);
    size_t origin_len = strlen(origin);
    if (!mem_len || !origin_len) {
        ret.error = CTOR_STR_BAD_STRLEN_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }

    // .source
    char *mem_c = malloc(mem_len + 1);
    if (!mem_c) {
        ret.error = CTOR_STR_MALLOC_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }
    strcpy(mem_c, mem);
    ret.source.string = (struct StringSource) {
            .begin = mem_c,
            .end = mem_c + mem_len + 1,
            .cur_pos = mem_c
    };

    // location
    char *origin_c = malloc(origin_len * sizeof(char) + 1);
    if (!origin_c) {
        free(ret.source.string.begin);
        ret.error = CTOR_STR_MALLOC_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }
    strcpy(origin_c, origin);
    ret.origin = origin_c;

    read_char(&ret);
    ret.line = 1;
    ret.index = 0;

    return ret;
}

struct Tokenizer tknr_from_filepath(const char *path) {
    struct Tokenizer ret = (struct Tokenizer) {
            .origin = NULL,
            .source.file = (struct FileSource) {
                    .eof = TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE,
                    .fptr = NULL,
                    .next_chars = {0},
                    .next_chars_pos = 0
            },
            .is_from_file = true,
            .next_char = '\0',
            .just_started = true,
            .error = 0
    };

    if (!path) {
        ret.error = CTOR_FILE_NULL_ARG_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }
    size_t path_len = strlen(path);
    if (!path_len) {
        ret.error = CTOR_FILE_BAD_STRLEN_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }

    // .source
    FILE *fptr = fopen(path, "rb");
    if (!fptr) {
        ret.error = CTOR_FILE_FOPEN_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }
    ret.source.file.fptr = fptr;

    // location
    char *path_c = malloc(path_len * sizeof(char) + 1);
    if (!path_c) {
        fclose(fptr);
        ret.error = CTOR_FILE_MALLOC_FAIL;
        return ret;
    }
    strcpy(path_c, path);
    ret.origin = path_c;

    struct FileSource *fs = &ret.source.file;
    size_t count = fread(fs->next_chars, sizeof(char), TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE, fs->fptr);
    if (count != TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE) {
        if (feof(fs->fptr)) {
            fs->eof = count;
        } else {
            fclose(fptr);
            free(ret.origin);
            ret.origin = NULL;
            ret.error = FILE_READ_FAIL;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    ret.next_char = fs->next_chars[0];
    fs->next_chars_pos = 1;

    ret.line = 1;
    ret.index = 0;

    return ret;
}

void tknr_free(struct Tokenizer *freeing) {
    // is this it? wow!
    if (freeing->origin) {
        free(freeing->origin);
        freeing->origin = NULL;
    }
    if (freeing->is_from_file) {
        if (freeing->source.file.fptr) {
            fclose(freeing->source.file.fptr);
            freeing->source.file.fptr = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        free(freeing->source.string.begin);
        freeing->source.string.begin = NULL;
        freeing->source.string.end = NULL;
        freeing->source.string.cur_pos = NULL;
    }
}

int get_next_char_file(struct Tokenizer *from) {
    struct FileSource *fs = &from->source.file;
    if (tknr_end(from)) {
        ERROR(FILE_READ_EOF_FAIL);
    } else if (fs->next_chars_pos == TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE) {
        size_t count = fread(fs->next_chars, sizeof(char), TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE, fs->fptr);
        if (count != TKNR_FILE_BUF_SIZE) {
            if (feof(fs->fptr)) {
                fs->eof = count;
            } else {
                return FILE_READ_FAIL;
            }
        }
        fs->next_chars_pos = 0;
    }
    from->next_char = fs->next_chars[fs->next_chars_pos++];
    return 0;
}

int get_next_char_string(struct Tokenizer *from) {
    struct StringSource *ss = &from->source.string;
    if (tknr_end(from)) {
        ERROR(STRING_READ_EOS_FAIL);
    } else {
        from->next_char = *ss->cur_pos;
        ++ss->cur_pos;
    }
    return 0;
}

char read_char(struct Tokenizer *reading) {
    if (reading->error) {
        ERROR(reading->error);
    }
    char ret = reading->next_char;
    int err = 0;
    if (reading->is_from_file) {
        err = get_next_char_file(reading);
    } else {
        err = get_next_char_string(reading);
    }
    if (err) {
        reading->error = err;
        // note that it's possible that '\0' is the next character. That's why the functions
        // that use this one not only check the return value of this but tknr_err(Tokenizer)
        return 0;
    }
    if (ret == '\n') {
        reading->index = 0;
        ++reading->line;
    } else {
        ++reading->index;
    }
    return ret;
}

char peek_char(struct Tokenizer *peeking) {
    if (peeking->error) {
        ERROR(peeking->error);
    }
    return peeking->next_char;
}

bool is_ws(char c) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t' ||
           c == '\n' || c == '\r';
}

bool skip_ws(struct Tokenizer *from) {
    bool skipped = false;
    while (is_ws(peek_char(from)) && !tknr_end(from)) {
        skipped = true;
        read_char(from);
    }
    return skipped;
}

bool skip_slc(struct Tokenizer *from) {
    if (peek_char(from) != '#') {
        return false;
    }
    while (peek_char(from) != '\n' && !tknr_end(from)) {
        read_char(from);
    }
    read_char(from); // take the newline
    return true;
}

bool skip_between(struct Tokenizer *from) {
    bool skipped = false;
    while (skip_ws(from) || skip_slc(from)) skipped = true;
    return skipped;
}

bool in_ranges(char c, char *begins, char *ends, size_t count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (begins[i] <= c && c <= ends[i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool add_while_in_ranges(struct Tokenizer *from, struct StringBuilder *raw, char *next_char,
                         char *begins, char *ends, size_t num_ranges) {
    *next_char = peek_char(from);
    while (in_ranges(*next_char, begins, ends, num_ranges)) {
        sb_append(raw, read_char(from));
        *next_char = peek_char(from);
        if (!(*next_char) && from->error) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool add_while_in_range(struct Tokenizer *from, struct StringBuilder *raw, char *next_char,
                        char begin, char end) {
    return add_while_in_ranges(from, raw, next_char, &begin, &end, 1);
}

#define STARTING_RAW_MEM 16

bool get_string(struct Tokenizer *from, char *next_char, struct Token partial, struct Token *out) {
    struct StringBuilder raw = sb_new();
    if (!sb_init(&raw, STARTING_RAW_MEM)) {
        from->error = NT_NEW_SB_FAIL;
        return NULL;
    }
    while (1) {
        sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
        if (tknr_end(from)) {
            from->error = SYN_UNEXPECTED_END_FAIL;
            goto error;
        }
        *next_char = peek_char(from);
        if (*next_char == '\\') {
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            if (from->error) {
                goto error;
            }
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            if (from->error) {
                goto error;
            }
        }
        if (*next_char == '\n') {
            from->error = SYN_STR_MULTILINE_FAIL;
            goto error;
        }
        if (*next_char == '"') {
            // add the quote
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            break;
        }
    }
    size_t raw_cstr_len = raw.count;
    char *raw_cstr = sb_into_string(raw);
    if (!raw_cstr) {
        from->error = NT_SB_FREE_COPY_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    partial.raw = raw_cstr;
    partial.raw_len = raw_cstr_len;
    partial.type = TKN_STRING;
    *out = partial;
    return true;
error:;
    sb_free(&raw);
    tkn_free(&partial);
    return false;
}

bool get_number(struct Tokenizer *from, char *next_char, struct Token partial, struct Token *out) {
    struct StringBuilder raw = sb_new();
    if (!sb_init(&raw, STARTING_RAW_MEM)) {
        from->error = NT_NEW_SB_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    partial.type = TKN_INTEGER;
    enum {
        B2, B8, B10, B16
    } base = B10;
    if (*next_char == '0') {
        sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
        *next_char = peek_char(from);
        if (*next_char == 'x') {
            base = B16;
        } else if (*next_char == 'o') {
            base = B8;
        } else if (*next_char == 'b') {
            base = B2;
        }
        sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
    }
    bool decimal = false;
    if (base == B16) {
        if (!add_while_in_ranges(from, &raw, next_char, "0aA", "9fF", 3)) {
            goto error;
        }
    } else if (base == B8) {
        if (!add_while_in_range(from, &raw, next_char, '0', '7')) {
            goto error;
        }
    } else if (base == B2) {
        if (!add_while_in_range(from, &raw, next_char, '0', '1')) {
            goto error;
        }
    } else if (base == B10) {
        // add decimal digits
        if (!add_while_in_range(from, &raw, next_char, '0', '9')) {
            goto error;
        }
        // un punto
        if (*next_char == '.') {
            decimal = true;
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            if (!add_while_in_range(from, &raw, next_char, '0', '9')) {
                goto error;
            }
        }
        // exponents
        if (*next_char == 'e') {
            decimal = true;
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            if (!add_while_in_range(from, &raw, next_char, '0', '9')) {
                goto error;
            }
        }
    }
    if (from->error) {
        goto error;
    }
    if (!is_ws(*next_char) && !tknr_end(from)) {
        from->error = SYN_NUM_ILLEGAL_DIGIT_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    partial.raw_len = raw.count;
    partial.raw = sb_into_string(raw);
    if (!partial.raw) {
        from->error = NT_SB_FREE_COPY_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    partial.type = decimal ? TKN_REAL : TKN_INTEGER;
    *out = partial;
    return true;
error:;
    sb_free(&raw);
    tkn_free(&partial);
    return false;
}

bool is_flag(char c) {
    return c == 'g' || c == 'x' ||
           c == 'i' || c == 'a' ||
           c == 'm' || c == 's';
}

bool get_regex(struct Tokenizer *from, struct StringBuilder raw, struct Token ret, struct Token *out) {
    sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
    char next_char = peek_char(from);
    while (true) {
        if (next_char == '\\') {
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            if (from->error) {
                goto error;
            } else if (tknr_end(from)) {
                from->error = SYN_UNEXPECTED_END_FAIL;
                goto error;
            }
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            if (from->error) {
                goto error;
            } else if (tknr_end(from)) {
                from->error = SYN_UNEXPECTED_END_FAIL;
                goto error;
            }
        }
        if (next_char == '/') {
            sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
            break;
        }
        sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
        if (from->error) {
            goto error;
        } else if (tknr_end(from)) {
            from->error = SYN_UNEXPECTED_END_FAIL;
            goto error;
        }
        next_char = peek_char(from);
    }
    next_char = peek_char(from);
    while (is_flag(next_char)) {
        sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
        next_char = peek_char(from);
    }
    if (!is_ws(next_char) && !tknr_end(from)) {
        from->error = SYN_RGX_BAD_FLAG_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    ret.type = TKN_REGEX;
    ret.raw_len = raw.count;
    ret.raw = sb_into_string(raw);
    if (!ret.raw) {
        from->error = NT_SB_FREE_COPY_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    *out = ret;
    return true;
error:;
    sb_free(&raw);
    tkn_free(&ret);
    return false;
}

bool tknr_next(struct Tokenizer *from, struct Token *out) {
    if (from->error) {
        ERROR(from->error);
    }
    if (tknr_end(from)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!skip_between(from)) {
        if (from->error) {
            return false;
        }
        // at the very beginning, it's OK not to have separation
        // (files don't have to start with code)
        if (!from->just_started) {
            from->error = SYN_NO_SEPARATION_FAIL;
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (from->just_started) {
        from->just_started = false;
    }
    if (tknr_end(from)) {
        return false;
    }

    struct StringBuilder raw = sb_new();
    struct Token ret = tkn_empty(from->line, from->index);
    ret.origin = malloc(from->origin_len * sizeof(char));
    if (!ret.origin) {
        from->error = NT_MALLOC_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    strcpy(ret.origin, from->origin);
    char next_char = peek_char(from);
    if (!next_char && from->error) {
        goto error;
    }
    if (next_char == '"') { // single-line string
        return get_string(from, &next_char, ret, out);
    } else if ('0' <= next_char && next_char <= '9') {
        return get_number(from, &next_char, ret, out);
    }
    if (!sb_init(&raw, STARTING_RAW_MEM)) {
        from->error = NT_NEW_SB_FAIL;
        goto error;
    }
    if (next_char == ':') {
        ret.type = TKN_IDENTIFIER;
    } else if (next_char == 'r') {
        sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
        next_char = peek_char(from);
        if (next_char == '/') {
            return get_regex(from, raw, ret, out);
        }
    }
    while (!is_ws(next_char) && !tknr_end(from)) {
        sb_append(&raw, read_char(from));
        next_char = peek_char(from);
    }
    if (ret.type == TKN_UNKNOWN) ret.type = TKN_WORD;
    ret.raw_len = raw.count;
    ret.raw = sb_into_string(raw);
    if (!ret.raw) {
        from->error = NT_SB_FREE_COPY_FAIL;
        sb_free(&raw);
    }
    *out = ret;
    return true;
error:;
    sb_free(&raw);
    tkn_free(&ret);
    return false;
}

bool tknr_end(struct Tokenizer *t) {
    if (t->is_from_file) {
        return t->source.file.eof < t->source.file.next_chars_pos;
    } else {
        return t->source.string.end == t->source.string.cur_pos;
    }
}

int tknr_err(struct Tokenizer *t) {
    return t->error;
}
```

*Wow* that's a lot of code. 623 + 66 = 689 LOC. Plus ~150 for the tests, which you can see [here](https://github.com/nic-hartley/concaten/blob/master/test/tokenizer.c).

As an example, this would turn the Hello World program, `"Hello, World!" puts` into two tokens: The string with raw value `"Hello, World!"` and the word `puts`. There very intentionally isn't a function defined to turn tokens into their Concaten values; that's defined in [`object.h`](https://github.com/nic-hartley/concaten/blob/master/object.h) and its `.c` (which will be up for review once it's done!)

A few things I'm concerned about:

- **Performance**, both in terms of speed and memory usage. Some things could definitely be improved. I haven't run a profiler yet; I want to finish the whole project to see where the biggest overall gains are. Probably something related to the dynamically-typed objects.
- **Bugs!** I've tested this code, and it works, but there are some things that concern me, though I'm not sure they're a problem. For example:

  - `*out = ret` doesn't seem like it should work. Is this undefined behavior that happens to be working, or is it well-defined as correct? I'm concerned because `ret` is memory on the stack, which is theoretically freed as soon as the method exits; I'm not convinced because (a) it works and (b) it might be copying the value, which is fine.
  - I'm not certain I didn't use anything I `free`d. There are a lot of code paths, and while I think I got them all, I obviously don't know about the ones I missed.
- **Memory leaks**. Did I `free` everything I `malloc`ed? Is there a circumstance where it's possible for that not to happen?
- **Code style**. And, similarly, readability -- I built this in bits and pieces from a groundwork that was... as well laid out as C let it be. It's still not very good. Anyway, because of its less than perfect origins <del>and my lack of C skill</del> it's not very good C style.

  - No, `goto` is not being counted as "bad C style", unless you can write a `finally` without convoluting things with an extra function call.

Comment: How can you say "I made this entirely from scratch" if you used a C compiler to make it? The question is not entirely facetious: Part of good software engineering is using appropriate tools. You could produce a flex-generated lexer with less than 20 lines of code, and the result would be easily maintainable, easily verifiable, and (most importantly IMHO) self-documenting about the nature of the tokens recognized. It would also probably be faster, but that's a minor consideration for lexical analysis.

Comment: @rici True. I also didn't manually write the code to get the characters from the disk. I didn't write `malloc`, or build the RAM with sand and a blowtorch. It doesn't diminish the challenge, and those caveats are understood when the language is specified. Also, I exaggerated; that was only half the point. The other half is to understand how things work behind the scenes; using a code generator doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes, that was my point about the C compiler, which is just a code generator. Do you need to program in assembler to understand how programs work, before you start using higher-level languages? Or is it better to start by seeing how functions, for example, are *used* before learning how they are *implemented*? I'd argue for the former.

Comment: @rici Right, but I've already seen, and used, tokenizers, both by programming in languages that use them and by using pre-made libraries in this thing's proof of concept. Like I said: Half the point of this is to see how things work behind the scenes. That's difficult if I don't _go there_. No, you don't need to program in Assembler to understand how code works, but if you want to not only understand what effects code has on your computer but also how it works, you need to either read the code, or read the code and rewrite your own version. The latter is better, IMO, and what I'm doing.

Comment: P.S. This has gotten a bit long and a bit off-topic for comments. If you'd like to continue in chat, I can create a room (and you might be able to; I don't remember what reputation you need to do so) for us to talk more in.

Comment: BTW if you're so worried about freeing everything you've `malloc`'d, here's an idea: keep a stack of arrays, in which you will keep the pointers to dynamically allocated memory. Write your own `xmalloc` function, which will call `malloc` and add the returned pointer to the topmost array. Once you're done with the data (like upon return from a function), you just do `mem_pop()` and all allocated memory since the last `mem_push()` (that is, all pointers in the topmost array plus the array) will be freed. `mem_XXX()` functions would operate on a global stack of arrays (all dynamically allocated).

Comment: @kyrill That seems like a lot of overkill, and like it'd introduce even more possible mistakes. I've run my tests through Valgrind, and it reported no leaks -- not even "still accessible" ones. I was only asking in case I missed something obvious :)

Comment: `skip_slc()` => `read_char(from); // take the newline`. What if it's not a newline, but `tknr_end`? Then `get_next_char_[file|string]` would call `ERROR`. Also, using your own buffer on top of system buffers _and_ stdio buffers is probably not of much use, especially if the buffer size is just 256 bytes. BTW have you implemented a regex engine yet? If not... you've a lot to look forward to ;)

Comment: @kyr Please post these as an answer :P

Answer (score 2):

#### Bug in copy

I didn't look at all your code.  I just scrolled to the bottom and took a look at the first big function, which happened to be `tknr_next()`.  Here is some code from that function:

> ```
> ret.origin = malloc(from->origin_len * sizeof(char));
> if (!ret.origin) {
>     from->error = NT_MALLOC_FAIL;
>     goto error;
> }
> strcpy(ret.origin, from->origin);
> ```

There are a couple of problems here:

1. `ret.origin` is allocated a buffer that is too small by 1, because `from->origin_len` doesn't include the null terminating character (I checked the other code to make sure).
2. After making the copy of the `origin` buffer from `from` to `ret`, you never set `ret->origin_len = from->origin_len`.  So `ret->origin_len` still has value `0`.  I'm not sure if this will cause problems later on, but I'm guessing that it might.

#### origin_len unset

Actually I just took another look at where `origin_len` comes from.  I found that neither `tknr_from_string()` nor `tknr_from_filepath()` set `ret->origin_len`.  So later in `tknr_next()` I believe that `from->origin_len` will always be 0, which seems like a problem unless I'm missing something.

#### *out = ret

You asked about whether `*out = ret` is correct.  This performs a struct copy, so even if `ret` will be destroyed when you return from the function, you have made a copy of all of its bytes to `*out`.  So it should be fine unless one of the fields of `ret` is a pointer to something local (and there aren't any fields like that).

#### Might be hard to extend

I'm not sure what your programming language's syntax looks like.  But I will imagine that is looks like C for the moment.  In the same function `tknr_next()`, you have this code:

> ```
> if (next_char == '"') { // single-line string
>     return get_string(from, &next_char, ret, out);
> } else if ('0' <= next_char && next_char <= '9') {
>     return get_number(from, &next_char, ret, out);
> }
> ...
> ```

This is OK as a start, but I wonder about:

1. What if instead of a digit, you have a negative number like `-5`?
2. What if instead of a digit, you have an expression starting with a parentheses, like `(5 + 5)`?
3. I don't see any support for operators, like `+`, `-`, `*`, etc.
4. Will your language support comments?  I don't see anything in your parser that would allow you to be in a "comment mode" where you parse malformed strings and such without generating an error.

In other words, I feel as if you are just getting started, and as you add additional features to your parser the code is going to get a lot more complicated.  You might want to define a grammar for your language and then work off of the grammar specification.  Even if you don't use `yacc`, having a formal grammar specification might force you to organize your code in ways you haven't thought of yet.

Honestly, if I had to write a language parser from scratch I wouldn't know how to do it either.  Good luck, because this may turn into a bigger project than you have anticipated.

Comment: The language doesn't look at _all_ like C, unless you write C very oddly. For an example of what it currently looks like, see [test.ctn](https://github.com/nic-hartley/concaten/blob/master/test.ctn). Also, the comments are in `skip_slc` -- they look like Python's (`# some random text\n`, where `\n` is a newline). You're right that I missed the case of negative numbers; I'm gonna add it in a moment. WRT "you're just getting started" -- Nope. That tokenizer, aside from any bugs, is done. WRT grammar specs -- I have one. It's in EBNF, it defines everything, and it... really didn't help at all.

Comment: WRT "I don't see any support for operators" specifically: Concaten is concatenative. That means that something you'd write as, say, `a + b` in C would be `a b +` in Concaten. In other words, there isn't such a thing as an infix operator; all I need to do is read until whitespace for a "function"; that in turn lets me have any character as part of the name, including those that'd normally be reserved for operators.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes So as you can tell, I didn't go to your website to look at your language or read the rest of the code at all.  Do you tokenize operators as just `TKN_WORD` then?

Comment: Yep, because they're words. It's, as far as I can tell, the standard name for concatenative languages' "functions". The Wikipedia page on [FORTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) has a good explanation buried in it, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer, as you suggested.

---

1. In function `skip_slc`, the loop condition is `peek_char(from) != '\n' && !tknr_end(from)`
2. When the loop terminates, either the next character is `'\n'` or **`tknr_end(from)` is nonzero**
3. After the loop, you call `read_char(from)`
4. Function `read_char` calls function `get_next_char_file` or `get_next_char_string` depending on the type of input
5. Both of these functions check whether **`tknr_end(from)` is nonzero**, and **in case it is, they call `ERROR`** with their respective error codes

That means you will get an error if there is a single-line comment at the very end of file.

---

A performance note: using your own buffer on top of system buffers and stdio buffers is probably not of much use, especially if the buffer size is just 256 bytes.